# One AD policy applied to some pc but not to others

Tags: active-directory, windows-7

I have the wsus server policy on all my lan's pc.
But now I changed wsus's policy from srv-vsus to srv-wsus. Ofter 10 days some client have applied the new policy then they correctly connect to the new srv-wsus server.
Other clients look they receipt the new policy but after some day they had become to the old.
Finally other client look did not have received the policy. The policy is at domain root level so I don't think there be some conflict between policies. Also the old policy there should not exist anymore. What's happens ? 
There are not any differences between windows 7 and xp clients. And gpresult give me the old policy configuration.